# Installing kernel headers packages missing error

Tags: linux, kali-linux, linux-kernel-headers

I am trying to install kernel-headers but getting this error

> E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-5.9.0-kali1-amd64

> E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-5.9.0-kali1-amd64'

> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-5.9.0-kali1-amd64'

I have updated and uncommented this line  in sources.list

> deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free

but errors thats can't locate `regex` or `glob`. what I am missing?

Comment: The **regex** and **glob** keywords means way how to target specific packages.  - Linux kernel 5.9.0 with kali patches in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you may need to do

```
sudo apt-get update # This will update the repositories list
sudo apt-get upgrade # This will update all the necessary packages on your system
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade # This will add/remove any needed packages
reboot # You may need this since sometimes after a upgrade/dist-upgrade, there are some left over entries that get fixed after a reboot
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) # This should work now
```

Comment: I like to create linux like small OS and run it on arduino uno. Any thoughts on that. How exactly I will create memory management's. Or how should I proceed. I initially planned some avr core. But what about minimal my own distribution.

Answer (score 1):

from what am guessing linux-headers-5.9.0 is not available in the kali repository.

you can always use apt-cache search linux-headers to know if it available
but to update to the latest linux headers

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

then search for Linux-headers available using apt search Linux-headers.

so you install the latest version using

```sh
sudo apt-get install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```